# What are iOS7's dynamic type CSS classes?

Tags: iphone, css, ios7

Or rather- is there a complete list of the CSS classes like
`-apple-system-headline1` etc available?

Comment: Would the downvote care to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet gives the complete list of values for dynamic fonts:
https://gist.github.com/linjunpop/6657893

You'll have to experiment in order to see their real usage, because Apple has not documented yet these values:
[Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-font)

Answer (score 1):

After some head scratching, I realized the currently accepted answer list is not completely correct (e.g. `-apple-system-headline1`). The official list can be found at Apple's website in their [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW31),  and is currently:

```
font: -apple-system-body;
font: -apple-system-headline;
font: -apple-system-subheadline;
font: -apple-system-caption1;
font: -apple-system-caption2;
font: -apple-system-footnote;
font: -apple-system-short-body;
font: -apple-system-short-headline;
font: -apple-system-short-subheadline;
font: -apple-system-short-caption1;
font: -apple-system-short-footnote;
font: -apple-system-tall-body;
```

I hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer5e195&utm_medium=google

I found this website after googling. There's a section on css if you scroll down a little bit. That might help you.

Comment: It does't unfortunately. I'm looking for a complete documentation: what are the styles, what are they used for, and all of them :(